# grails - custom userType with 2 columns and query

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails

Let's say I've a POJO representing coordinates (lat and long) and domain classes representing places. Places have a coordinate.

Coordinate.groovy

```
class Coordinate implements Serializable{
    float latitude
    float longitude
    ...
}
```

CoordinateUserType.groovy

```
class CoordinateUserType implements UserType{

    int[] sqlTypes() { [Types.FLOAT, Types.FLOAT]}

    public Object nullSafeGet(rs, names, owner){
        /*not full code published, just what is relevant*/
        return new Coordinate(rs.getFloat(names[0]), rs.getFloat(names[1]))
    }
    public Object nullSafeSet(st, object, index){
        /*not full code published, just what is relevant*/
        st.setFloat(index, value.latitude)
        st.setFloat(index+1, value.longitude)
    }


}
```

Place.groovy

```
class Place{
    ...
    Coordinate coordinate
    ...
    static mapping = {
        coordinate type:CoordinateUserType, {
            column name:'latitude'
            column name:'longitude'
        }
    }

}
```

I created a userType for coordinates (2 columns) and reference it in mapping of places domain class.

I can create and list places correctly.

But I'd like to query the places based on their coordinates, something like

With where :

```
def matchingPlaces = Place.where{
    coordinate.latitude > 0 && coordinate.latitude < 10 &&
    coordinate.longitude > 0 && coordinate.longitude < 10
}
```

with criteria :

```
def matchingPlaces = Place.createCriteria().list{
    and{
        between('coordinate.latitude', 0,10)
        between('coordinate.longitude', 0,10)
    }
}
/*or */
def matchingPlaces = Place.createCriteria().list{
    coordinate{
        and{
            between('latitude', 0,10)
            between('longitude', 0,10)
        }
    }
}
```

But whatever I type in the column name of the between closure, I always get an error "Could not resolve property".

What's the procedure to query custom user types with multiple columns?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `embed` in your `Place`:

```
static embedded = ['coordinate']
```

You do not need the custom mapping and can remove `CoordinateUserType` then as well.

The following will work then:

```
def matchingPlaces = Place.createCriteria().list{
    coordinate{
        and{
            between('latitude', 0,10)
            between('longitude', 0,10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks! Why do complicated... I found another solution with UserType using CompositeUserType and querying with HQL but your solution is far easier. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your domain looks like this:

```
class Place {
    ...
    Coordinate coordinate
    ...
}
```

You could access this nested domain within your criteria like this:

```
coordinate{
    and {
        between('latitude', 0, 10)
        between('longitude', 0, 10)
    }
}
```

Not tested but should work ...